# Joining multiple resultsets

Tags: sql

I have four Select queries for four different tables, each extracting only one record. For example:

```
Select * from table where col1 = 'something'
```

gives one row having 3 columns.

The second select query also gives one record having two columns(fields). Same for third and fourth select query.

I want to combine all four ResultSets into one having one row. How is it possible?

I will write the queries for you

1st one

```
Select Top 1 column1,column2 from table 1 where column 1 = 'something' 
and col1 = (Select max(col1) where column 1 = 'something')
```

2nd query

```
Select Top 1 column1 , column3 from table 2 where column 1 = 'something' 
and column3 = (Select max(column3) where column 1 = 'something')
```

3rd query use result obtained from query 2

```
Select column4 ,column3 from table 3 
where column3 = (obtained from 2nd query) (there is only one row)
```

4th

```
Select column5 from table 4 
where column3 = (obtained from 2nd query) (there is only one row)
```

this means I have to join 2nd ,3rd ,4th query then resultant set int 1st

I can't use union since column are different

so only problem is with joining the result set

I hope it explains

Result set 
Sql query1

column1 column2

aaa              bbb

Sql query 2

column1  column3

aaa              cccc

Sql query 3

column3 column4

cccc           dddd

sql query 4

column3  column5

cccc           eeee

The resultant set

coulumn1 column2 column3 column4 column5

aaa      bbb     cccc    dddd    eeee

hope the reultset explains everything

Comment: It seems you are asking same question repeatedly... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882039/combining-resultset-of-many-select-queries) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876790/combining-resultset-obtained-by-select-statements-to-create-a-view) and it's not like your questions were ignored. You just chose to _not to give credit who worked for you_ or discussed further.

Comment: downvoted for not following up on your earlier questions.

Answer (score 1):

Make the column number and types the same for all queries by adding columns (even if you don't need them):

```
Select column4, column3 from table 3 
where column3 = ...

Select column5, column3 from table 4 
where column3 = ...
```

As an aside, it looks likely that your query can be simplified considerably. It's quite messy at the moment.

Perhaps you should re-phrase your question to explain in English what you are trying to do and what your table schema is, and let *us* suggest the *whole* query.

Comment: Actually i want to combine the 4 different Result sets

Comment: Please see the result set to get the picture of problem

Comment: I deliberately left out the other selects because they don't need to change. Just add them in.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1(c1 varchar(10), c2 varchar(10), c3 varchar(10), c4 varchar(10), c5 varchar(10));

create table table2(c1 varchar(10), c2 varchar(10), c3 varchar(10), c4 varchar(10), c5 varchar(10));

create table table3(c1 varchar(10), c2 varchar(10), c3 varchar(10), c4 varchar(10), c5 varchar(10));

create table table4(c1 varchar(10), c2 varchar(10), c3 varchar(10), c4 varchar(10), c5 varchar(10));

insert into table1 values (1,2,3,4,5);

insert into table2 values (1,5,3,7,8);

insert into table3 values (1,15,3,17,18);

insert into table4 values (1,22,3,24,25);


  with max3 as
  (select c1, max(c3) c3 from table2 where table2.c1 = 1 group by c1)
  select table1.c1, table1.c2, max3.c3, table3.c4, table4.c5
    from table1
    join max3
      on max3.c1 = table1.c1
    join table3
      on table3.c3 = max3.c3
    join table4
      on table4.c3 = max3.c3
   where table1.c1 = 1;
```

*output*

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 
 1  2  3 17 25
```

Comment: As written, this should be equivalent to the queries you posted.  Please post the exact schema, some data and the queries you have tried if this doesn't match what you want.